# Insert line break into SQL Query embedded in Excel Workbook Connection

Tags: sql, excel, t-sql

**Using:** t-SQL, SSMS 2008, Excel 2010

**Background:** I have a SQL query that I've embedded into an Excel workbook via Connection that the end user can refresh. This query returns a column with a long string of sentences, basically a paragraph (this column's datatype is flexible).

**What I Am Trying To Do:** I would like each sentence of the paragraph to start on a new line in the Excel cell that it's in.

**Example of UNDESIRED formatting:**
[image]

**Example of DESIRED formatting:**
[image]

**What I've Tried:** I've tried adding the CHAR(13) linebreak to the SQL query. It correctly prints the paragraph with the desired line breaks in SSMS, but it doesn't transfer over to Excel, when the workbook is refreshed.

Comment: IS the excel document formatted to allow wrapping of text? and do you need char(10)+char(13)? (vbcrlf) (carrige return line feed)

Comment: @xQbert Let me try each of these now, and I will report back

Comment: @xQbert Looks like that was it! It was a combination of both enabling text wrapping and adding CHAR(10) to the CHAR(13) that I already had. If you'd like to make your comment an answer, I'd be happy to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if you really need the wrapping of text.  But I'm pretty sure you need both char(10) and char(13) carriage return and line feed (vbcrlf) equivalent.

Comment: Thank you much for your answer!! Btw, I tested it without wrapping and it did NOT work.

Comment: For anyone who reads this answer, here is an example of how it will work, assuming you have text wrap enabled in Excel:     select 'This is a paragraph.' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'It contains many sentences.' + CHAR(10) + CHAR(13) + 'I would like each sentence to start on a new line w/in the cell.'